# libSVM giving highly inaccurate predictions even for the file that was used to train it

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svm, libsvm, pos-tagger

here is the deal.
I am trying to make an SVM based POS tagger.
The feature vectors for the SVM was created with the help of format converters. 
Now here is a screenshot of the training file that I am using.
http://tinypic.com/r/n4fn2r/8

I have 25 labels for various POS tags. when i use the java implementation or the command line tools for prediction i get the following results.
http://tinypic.com/r/2dtw5ky/8

I have tried with all the kernels available but it gave more or less the same results.
This is happening even when the training file is used as the testing file.
please help me out here..!! 
P.S. I cannot share more than two links. Thus here is a snippet of the model file

```
    svm_type c_svc
    kernel_type rbf
gamma 0.000548546
nr_class 25
total_sv 431
rho -0.929467 1.01073 1.0531 1.03472 1.01585 0.953263 1.03027 -0.921365 0.984535 1.02796 1.01266 1.03374 0.949463 0.977925 0.986551 -0.920912 0.940926 -0.955562 0.975386 -0.981959 -0.884042 0.0516955 -0.980884 -0.966095 0.995091 1.023 1.01489 1.00308 0.948314 1.01137 -0.845876 0.968034 1.0076 1.00064 1.01335 0.942633 0.965703 0.979212 -0.861236 0.935055 -0.91739 0.970223 -0.97103 0.0743777 0.970321 -0.971215 -0.931582 0.972377 0.958193 0.931253 0.825797 0.954894 -0.972884 -0.941726 0.945077 0.922366 0.953999 -1.00503 0.840985 0.882229 -0.961742 0.791631 -0.984971 0.855911 -0.991528 -0.951211 -0.962096 -0.99213 -0.99708 -0.957557 -0.308987 -0.455442 -0.94881 -0.995319 -0.974945 -0.964637 -0.902152 -0.955258 -1.05287 -1.00614 -0.
```

*update*
Just trained the SVM with svm type as c-SVC and kernel type as linear. Which gave a non-zero(although very poor) accuracy.

Comment: what is the classification accuracy that you are getting?

Comment: it says 0/431 (0% accuracy)

Comment: which svm tool are you using? also, why does the nr_class show a value of 25? shouldn't it be 14 in your case?

Comment: I am using the libSVM tools. I am sorry. The actual number of tags is 25 including the one for unknown (_UNK)=0.

Comment: i can't give u a definite answer bcoz u haven't provided enough information e.g. what are the features and how many of them, how many instances are u using for training etc.. i would suggest u to have a look at the features themselves bcoz an accuracy of 0 is hard to achieve... even a random classification would give you a positive accuracy...

Comment: but i think it should give a good result for the training file at least.!! And i don't seem to understand how do the feature's details matter at all. When both the training and testing file have been made by using the same converter.

Comment: Aren't you using setting up the C value? It is highly unlikely that you won't have any good result with the default value. Also, a it is quite normal not getting valid results for the training set if the underlying optimization problem is not feasible (small C, incorrect gamma value, etc). On the other hand, consider to rescale the feature values to the range [0,1]

Comment: what value of C and gamma do you suggest that i should use.? or if you can give me some link to a tutorial of some sort that would be equally helpful.

Comment: u said u have 25 classes... how many training data points are u using to train a svm?

Comment: you mean how many words i had in the train file which i converted to the SVM format. right..? 
Well its nearly 431 words.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Pedrom, parameter choice is absolutely crucial when training SVMs. I suggest you have a look at [this practical guide](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf). Also, 431 words is nowhere near enough to train a 25-class model. You will definitely need more data.

That said, 0% accuracy is indeed odd. Can you please show us the commands you are using to train and evaluate the model?

Comment: I have used svm command line tools with default values. (and sometimes non default values as well.) 
`svm-train *file name* *desired model name*
svm-predict *test file* *model file* *output file* `